# How do you bulk move files into folders corresponding to the name of each file?

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename, mv, batch

I have several movies in a folder.

For example:

```
~/Downloads/Movies/Movie A (1998).mkv  
~/Downloads/Movies/Movie B (1999).mkv  
~/Downloads/Movies/Movie C (2000).mkv
```

I would like to put each file into its own folder, and name the folder identical to the file name. I have many files, so I would like to be able to do this in a batch if possible.

For example:

```
~/Downloads/Movies/Movie A (1998)/Movie A (1998).mkv
~/Downloads/Movies/Movie B (1999)/Movie B (1999).mkv
~/Downloads/Movies/Movie C (2000)/Movie C (2000).mkv
```

I have tried to use the bash command on [this page](https://github.com/Radarr/Radarr/wiki/Create-a-Folder-for-Each-Movie)

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -exec sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" ; mv "" "${1%.*}" ' _ {} \;
```

However, I get the error message:

```
mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
```

The folder is created correctly, but the command fails to move the file into the folder, and I get the above error.

Which part of

```
; mv "" "${1%.*}" ' _ {} \;
```

is incorrect, and how so?

Also, if there are other commands or scripts you think would do the job, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`""` should be `"$1"`. That argument of `mv` should be the file to be moved, and obviously it can't be left empty.

Comment: @MartinJS Glad you found a solution! Please click the checkmark below the vote arrows. This will "accept" the answer, and it effectively marks your question as "resolved".